# assign clob variable to a java stream (myBatis)

Tags: java, mybatis, clob, typehandler

I've a clob variable as a return value of a PL-SQL procedure. I want to assign this clob variable to a Java stream variable. I think that the easy way to do this is the implementation of a custom typeHandler in myBatis. I'm new with myBatis and I don't find any help on Google. Can you give me some advices to resolve my problem?

Note: the clob variable is not a "column variable" (in that case I know how can resolve the problem) but an INOUT variable.

Comment: See [Clob](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html).

Comment: Hi Joop I know Clob, but I can retrieve the jdbc clob to get it into java.sql.Clob? in the mapper config file if i use this:
{result, mode=INOUT, jdbcType=CLOB, javaType=java.sql.Clob }
I have an exception of this type: no typeHandler defined for result.
So I must write a typeHandler

Comment: Sorry, cannot help you there; at the moment no project with mybatis.